# How to get Mac OS X style 'Quick Look' feature in Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, nautilus, previews

Sometimes Nautilus' icon thumbnails and/or metadata for a file, photo, or folder just aren't good enough to make sure it's the desired file.

Is there an app for Ubuntu similar to [Mac OSX's "Quick Look" feature](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18813?locale=en_US) in order to get a closer look without opening the file?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**GNOME Sushi** can add a Mac OSX style "Quick Look" feature to the Nautilus file manager. It is not installed by default, but you can install it. Open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-sushi
```

**How to use:** Just select a file and tap the <kbd>Space</kbd> bar to see a larger (and sometimes interactive) preview.

**Features:**

1. It can provide an instant preview of a folder, image, music or a video file using the `GStreamer` framework.

   [image]

   [image]
2. Sushi also supports previewing most plain text documents, including scripts with syntax highlighting, PDFs, and HTML files.

   [image]

It's a quick and effective way to take a quick peek at PDFs, photos, MP3s,   videos, and other documents without having to fully open them.

***Note:*** Unfortunately, unlike OSX, Sushi doesn't update the preview window if you move off of it and select other files. <sup>[Source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/09/gnome-sushi-mac-quick-look-nautilus)</sup>

Comment: I can add that in the version 3.34.0-2 (which is the current one on ubuntu 20.04) the preview successfully updates when changing the focus via arrow keys or mouse.